# Removing and adding Bootstrap 4 alert classes breaks alert type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am making an alert system for a web application with Bootstrap 4. Here is my code:

```js
function bsalert(str1, str2) {

    $(".alert").addClass('show');

    $(".alert").addClass('alert-'+str1);

    $('.alert').html(str2);

    setTimeout( function() {
        $(".alert").removeClass('show');
        $(".alert").removeClass('alert-'+str1);
    }, 2000 );

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="alert alert-dismissible fade text-center" role="alert" id="alert"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="bsalert('danger', 'ALERT!');">one</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="bsalert('success', 'nice');">two</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The issue I am having is if you do it too quickly, before the timer removes the class, it breaks the ability to change alert types. How can I fix this? Does Bootstrap have a better function built in?

Edit: In this example I simplified the number of types of alerts, in actually there's more than just `danger` and `success`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it help you

```js
var timer;
function bsalert(str1, str2) {

      clearTimeout(timer)
      $(".alert").removeClass('show');
      $(".alert").removeClass('alert-danger');
      $(".alert").removeClass('alert-success');

    $(".alert").addClass('show');

    $(".alert").addClass('alert-'+str1);

    $('.alert').html(str2);
    
    timer=setTimeout( function() {
        $(".alert").removeClass('show');
        $(".alert").removeClass('alert-'+str1);
    }, 2000 );

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="alert alert-dismissible fade text-center" role="alert" id="alert"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="bsalert('danger', 'ALERT!');">one</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="bsalert('success', 'nice');">two</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, in this example I simplified the amount of types of alerts. There's much more than just the two (danger and success) in the example, do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Now if you use the set time out function the alert will hide in 2 seconds interval so in the meantime if the notification is clicked many times continuously it will still hide the element in 2 seconds which can create an effect where you see it going off very quickly, there are few solutions to which: either you post an element with different id for every notification,  or you restrict the function call or delay it after two seconds, or disable the notification button for 2 seconds so the notification is called only after every 2 seconds,also you can use the clear timeout function of javascript.

```js
var timeoutElem;

function bsalert(str1, str2) {
  var alertClassString = 'alert-' + str1;
  var existingClass = '';
  clearTimeout(timeoutElem);
  existingClass = (str1 === "danger") ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger';
  $(".alert").removeClass(existingClass);
  $(".alert").addClass(alertClassString);
  $(".alert").removeClass('show');
  $(".alert").addClass('show');
  $('.alert').html(str2);
  timeoutElem = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").removeClass('show');
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="alert alert-dismissible fade text-center" role="alert" id="alert"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="bsalert('danger', 'ALERT!');">one</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="bsalert('success', 'nice');">two</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, in this example I simplified the amount of types of alerts. There's much more than just the two (danger and success) in the example, do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Well in case of that what you can do is send the whole class attribute in that section,  in a function if you don't know which alert is coming and all is dynamic, so you can replace the full class attribute to it that way you do not have to worry about which class is coming and which class you have to replace before showing the new alert. you can directly replace the class with .attr jquery function and this will help you updated your solution accordingly.Also, you can make a function with the different class-related alert types and save an already executed alert before its call in that manner